# android:layout_marginStart and android:layout_marginEnd

Tags: android-layout

I'm using android:layout_marginStart and android:layout_marginEnd in my code.

But couldn't understand their usage.
Can anyone explain?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

layout_marginStart and layout_marginEnd are the same as layout_marginLeft and layout_marginRight for left-to-right (LTR) languages.

For right-to-left (RTL) languages (Arabic, Hebrew, etc.), layout_marginStart and layout_marginEnd reverse and become equivalent to layout_marginRight and layout_marginLeft, respectively.

If we use android:layout_marginStart = “10dp”, then we will have to use android:layout_marginEnd = “some dp value”. Else it will not work. No error, but output will be wrong.

Suppose, we take android:layout_marginStart  and layout_marginLeft, then the output will not be correct.

So, always use android:layout_marginStart and layout_marginEnd together.